Cursor dissapears when usin PostAsync .Net Maui
I am Posting a JSON in .Net Maui to HTTPClient that works correctly the most time. But sometimes it fails.
I have RestService class that contains a method called PostJason and my code is inside try/catch but when it reaches the POST line, the cursor of the program dissapear and it doesn´t continues the program and never pass through catch.
I have tested it with a break point and that is the line that sometimes fails.
Repeat the most of the time that I call this method, it works Ok and the Post works fine... Maybe 1 in 30 times has an error.. I don´t post all my code because is very extensive...
The json parameter is passed when I call this class..
    public static class JsonCreatorHelper
    {
        public static string CreateInvoiceJson(Order order)
        {
            var invoice = new
            {
                id = order.Id,

                reference = order.Reference,

                customer_id = order.Client.idEmpresa,              
            
                invoice_date = order.DateCreation.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffffZ"),

                importe_anticipo = order.AdvanceAmount,

                lines = CreateOrderLinesJson(order.OrderLines)
            };

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invoice, Formatting.Indented);
        }

        private static List<object> CreateOrderLinesJson(List<OrderLines> orderLines)
        {
            var lines = new List<object>();

            foreach (var line in orderLines)
            {
                var lineJson = new
                {
                    id = line.Id,

                    article_id = line.ProductId,

                    external_id = line.ProductId,                    

                    total = line.Total
                };

                lines.Add(lineJson);
            }

            return lines;
        }
    }
}

Could you tell me why can it happen and if there is any other way to solve this?
public static class RestService
{
    //Fields

    private static HttpClient _client;

    private static JsonSerializerOptions _serializerOptions;

    private const string _baseUrl = "https://abetekapimng.azure-api.net";


    //Constructor

    static RestService()
    {
     _client = new HttpClient();

     _serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    }


   //Method

   private static async Task PostJason(string endpoint, string json)
   {
     try
     {      
         var url = $"{_baseUrl}{endpoint}";

         StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");                      

         var response = await _client.PostAsync(url, content); //This is the line that sometimes fails; it doesn´t continue to next line or catch

         response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

         string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

         
     }
     catch
     {
         
         await MessagesHelper.DisplayAlert("Error al sincronizar el albaran");
                         
     }`
 



I need to understand the problem

What platform does this problem happen on? And is there any log about this problem?

Visual Studio 2022 but i don´t see any log..

Have you checked the Output window of your visual studio?

Yes, but i don´t see anything... I´ll try to force the error and paste Output window..

You can use Postman to send post request to your web services for several times, will you get the error code like 500 or 403 error code? Which platform do you have this issue? Such as windows, android or iOS platforms.
